# Inconsistent locale case sensitivity in Java compared to Bash

Tags: java, bash, date, locale, simpledateformat

When I try to format Date in Polish, I get consistent formatting:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.forLanguageTag("pl-PL")).format(new Date())
```

results in

```
wtorek
```

The same result in bash:

```
LC_ALL=pl_PL
$ date +"%A %b %d"
wtorek maj 22
```

Notice both lowercase `w` in `wtorek`.

When I do that for Czech language, the result is incosistent:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.forLanguageTag("cs-CZ").format(new Date())
```

results in

```
Pondělí
```

When run in bash:

```
$ LC_ALL=cs_CZ 
$ date +"%A %b %d"
pondělí kvě 21
```

Notice the uppercase `P` in the Java result. How does this happen? Does it mean `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't use standard Locales installed on the system?

Comment: For what it’s worth: on Java 8, where Java’s own locale data, known as COMPAT, previously as JRE, are used, I get `Úterý` with capital U with accent. On Java 9, where CLDR are used as default, I get `úterý` with small u. Not directly related, I recommend you stop using `SimpleDateFormat`, it is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, instead.

Comment: I tried using the `java.time` and unfortunately it suffers from the same issue.

Comment: Yes, Vojtěch, `java.time` uses the same locale data, so I would have been surprised if there had been any difference. There are just so many other troubles with `SimpleDateFormat` and no reason that I can see why you should want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean SimpleDateFormat doesn't use standard Locales installed on the system

Yes, system locales are not used and available Locales depend on JVM/JRE vendor. For example check `lib\ext\localedata.jar` in JRE directory. After extracting you can find file: `sun\text\resources\cs\FormatData_cs_CZ.class` that decompiles into:

```
public class FormatData_cs extends ParallelListResourceBundle
{
    @Override
    protected final Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] { { "MonthNames", 
        { "ledna", "\u00fanora", "b\u0159ezna", "dubna", "kv\u011btna", "\u010dervna", "\u010dervence", "srpna", "z\u00e1\u0159\u00ed", "\u0159\u00edjna", "listopadu", "prosince", "" } }, 
        { "standalone.MonthNames", { "leden", "\u00fanor", "b\u0159ezen", "duben", "kv\u011bten", "\u010derven", "\u010dervenec", "srpen", "z\u00e1\u0159\u00ed", "\u0159\u00edjen", "listopad", "prosinec", "" } }, 
        { "MonthAbbreviations", { "Led", "\u00dano", "B\u0159e", "Dub", "Kv\u011b", "\u010cer", "\u010cvc", "Srp", "Z\u00e1\u0159", "\u0158\u00edj", "Lis", "Pro", "" } }, 
        { "standalone.MonthAbbreviations", { "I", "II", "III", "IV", "V", "VI", "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII", "" } }, 
        { "MonthNarrows", { "l", "\u00fa", "b", "d", "k", "\u010d", "\u010d", "s", "z", "\u0159", "l", "p", "" } },
        { "standalone.MonthNarrows", { "l", "\u00fa", "b", "d", "k", "\u010d", "\u010d", "s", "z", "\u0159", "l", "p", "" } }, 
        { "DayNames", { "Ned\u011ble", "Pond\u011bl\u00ed", "\u00dater\u00fd", "St\u0159eda", "\u010ctvrtek", "P\u00e1tek", "Sobota" } }, 
        { "standalone.DayNames", { "ned\u011ble", "pond\u011bl\u00ed", "\u00fater\u00fd", "st\u0159eda", "\u010dtvrtek", "p\u00e1tek", "sobota" } }, 
        { "DayAbbreviations", { "Ne", "Po", "\u00dat", "St", "\u010ct", "P\u00e1", "So" } }, 
        { "standalone.DayAbbreviations", { "ne", "po", "\u00fat", "st", "\u010dt", "p\u00e1", "so" } }, 
        { "DayNarrows", { "N", "P", "\u00da", "S", "\u010c", "P", "S" } }, 
        { "standalone.DayNarrows", { "N", "P", "\u00da", "S", "\u010c", "P", "S" } },
        { "AmPmMarkers", { "dop.", "odp." } }, 
        { "Eras", { "p\u0159.Kr.", "po Kr." } }, 
        { "short.Eras", { "p\u0159. n. l.", "n. l." } }, 
        { "narrow.Eras", { "p\u0159.n.l.", "n. l." } }, 
        { "NumberElements", { ",", " ", ";", "%", "0", "#", "-", "E", "\u2030", "\u221e", "\ufffd" } }, 
        { "TimePatterns", { "H:mm:ss z", "H:mm:ss z", "H:mm:ss", "H:mm" } }, 
        { "DatePatterns", { "EEEE, d. MMMM yyyy", "d. MMMM yyyy", "d.M.yyyy", "d.M.yy" } }, 
        { "DateTimePatterns", { "{1} {0}" } }, 
        { "DateTimePatternChars", "GuMtkHmsSEDFwWahKzZ" } };
    }
}
```

and contains "Pond\u011bl\u00ed" in "DayNames".

Comment: Does your source come from Oracle or OpenJDK?

Answer (score 4):

Java picks up its locale data (including the names of the days of the week in different locales) from up to four sources. And yes, the host operating system is one of them, but is not the default. To quote [the `LocaleServiceProvider` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html):

> Java Runtime Environment provides the following four locale providers:
>
> - "CLDR": A provider based on Unicode Consortium's CLDR Project.
> - "COMPAT": represents the locale sensitive services that is compatible    with the prior JDK releases up to JDK8 (same as JDK8's
>     "JRE").
> - "SPI":    represents the locale sensitive services implementing the subclasses    of this LocaleServiceProvider class.
> - "HOST": A provider that reflects    the user's custom settings in the underlying operating system. This    provider may not be
>     available, depending on the Java Runtime    Environment
>     implementation.
> - "JRE": represents a synonym to "COMPAT".    This name is deprecated and will be removed in the future release of    JDK.

Up to Java 8 JRE was the default. I am using `java.time` because no one should take the trouble with the outdated `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayOfWeekFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.forLanguageTag("cs-CZ"));
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Prague"));
    System.out.println(date.format(dayOfWeekFormatter));
```

Output running on my Oracle jdk1.8.0_131 agrees with your result (uppercase `S`):

> Středa

We may control the locale data used through a system property. To prefer CLDR, for example, either run the program with VM command line option `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR,COMPAT` or insert the following line at the start of the program:

```
    System.setProperty("java.locale.providers", "CLDR,COMPAT");
```

> středa

Now we get the lowercase `s`.

My shell on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 just gives `Wednesday`, so apparently my OS hasn’t got Czech locale data (which sounds weird; probably the issue is somewhere else), and thus is not an option for me. You may try putting `HOST` in front of the above locale provider string and see if what you get agrees with your `bash`.

In Java 9 and later CLDR is the default. So running the same snippet on jdk9.0.4 without setting any system property also gives day of week in lowercase:

> středa